# Using Powershell pipe to add dynamic property to a collection of objects by calling function

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of objects, each one with one property called as ProductName. I also defined a function to get parts for a product:

```
function GetParts([string] ProductName))
{
   $parts = @()
   ....
   return $parts
}
```

What I need is to use pipe to loop each object and add "Parts" as another property to the object by calling my function, and finally output the collection to a table view:

```
$products | Sort-Object ProductName | Select-Object `
  -Property ProductName, `
            @{Expression=(GetParts $_.ProductName); Label="Parts"} | `
          Format-Table ProductName, Parts
```

I put a break point in my function, but I don't get debug stop. Not sure how to use pipe for a collection with my function to add a dynamic property (Parts).

Comment: So it looks like you want the function to output an object with 2 properties, the first being a string `ProductName`, and the second being an array of strings `Parts`. Is that right? Or do you want it to output an array of objects that have 2 properties, one being a string for the `ProductName` and then each individual part that makes up the collection of `Parts`?

Comment: Two properties: `ProductName` and `Parts` (an array of strings). Is there any way to use pipe to call my function to output information I need?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Thanks and by the way your link doesn't work

Comment: I believe the expression in a calculate property needs to be wrapped in braces {} , not parens ().

Comment: For adding a property you'll need to use Add-Member, see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730946.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The expression in your calculated property must be in curly brackets, not parentheses. Change this:

```
Select-Object -Property ProductName, `
    @{Expression=(GetParts $_.ProductName); Label="Parts"}
```

into this:

```
select ProductName, @{Label='Parts';Expression={GetParts $_.ProductName}}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get it to accept values from the pipe use the parameter option `ValueFromPipeline` like this:

```
function GetParts{
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$ProductName
    )
    Process{
       $parts = @()
       ....
       return New-Object PSObject -Property @{ProductName=$ProductName;Parts=$parts}
    }
}
```

That will return an object with the desired properties, and accept values from the pipe.

Comment: Why do you use `New-Object` when you can just use `Add-Member` to add a new property to an existing object?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Because he is inputting a string, so if I just added a property it wouldn't output an object with two properties it would output a string containing the input, and a property on that string object with the array of parts. In short, it didn't give him the output he desired.